# What does vetted role mean?

Tags: community-official-site

I just read in drupal.org site [this comment](https://www.drupal.org/project/projectownership/issues/3103361#comment-13409979):

> A user who doesn't have the vetted role cannot become the only
> maintainer, or the project maintainer, of a project that opted into
> security coverage, in the same way a user without the vetted role
> cannot take over a project that opted into security coverage.

I tried to found what is this on the site without luck and I really don't have an idea.

Does somebody know what means vetted role in drupal.org?

Comment: In literal terms, it means that someone has critiqued the person's ability to write secure code. Are you looking for more of a specific explanation of what that process involves?

Comment: @Clive will be great to have more information, today is the first time I read about this, I think will be a great answer for other persons searching for the same.

Comment: Where did you read this? What comment? In what context?

Comment: @leymannx check the link I added to the question

Comment: Thank you Adrian, that makes it clearer.

Comment: Oh, that's a comment I wrote.

Comment: @kiamlaluno yes, and was the first time I saw that term

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order for a Drupal contributed module to be eligible to be tagged as a security monitored project, one or more of the maintainers have to be 'vetted'.

Here is the main [Drupal security policy](https://www.drupal.org/drupal-security-team/security-advisory-process-and-permissions-policy) on this.  See the "Which Projects are covered" section.  There is a link in this to the [process of becoming 'vetted'](https://www.drupal.org/project/projectapplications).

Basically, you submit a Drupal.org project to a queue.  Eventually, security community members will review it for use of best security practices, code quality, and some other stuff.  If approved, the maintainer becomes 'vetted'.  Unfortunately, this process can take a long time to happen.

Once you have a project approved and are 'vetted', any other projects you maintain can be labeled as covered by the security community.

Comment: This process is new? I never passed the process and I maintain many modules.

Comment: It usually doesn't take that long anymore nowadays. The [queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/search/projectapplications) has been worked on pretty actively by the community.

Comment: The vetting process is has been around for a LONG time.  This one is the modified process that was put into place after they changed the contrib rules to allow anyone to create a full project.  The vetting process before that was used to determine if you were allowed to create a full project and not just a sandbox project.

Answer (score 5):

I used the term *vetted role* because *vetted* is the term that appears in the user profile, to users that on Drupal.org have the *Git administrator* role.

> [image: screenshot]

In places listing the possible roles Drupal.org can have, *Git vetted user* is one of them.

> [image: screenshot]

Before the ability of opting into security advisory coverage was introduced, that role allowed users to create a full project; without that role, user were only able to create sandbox projects. That is when the *vetted* role was introduced.

Nowadays, the documentation speaks of being able to opt into security coverage, for example [Apply for permission to opt into security advisory coverage](https://www.drupal.org/node/1011698) or [Security advisory process and permissions policy](https://www.drupal.org/drupal-security-team/security-advisory-process-and-permissions-policy). The term *vetted* is still mentioned in those pages, but in *Security advisory process and permissions policy* it appears only once. (It's probable that most users would not catch what *vetted* means, nor they will notice that term.)

Today, users who want to apply to opt into security coverage for the projects they create are the ones going to get the *vetted* role. Those aren't the only users who have that role, though. The *vetted* role has been given to:

- Users who have asked for the permission to be able to create full project (and not only sandbox projects). Now every user, even the ones who don't have the *confirmed* role, can create full projects, but they still need the *vetted* role to opt into security coverage for the projects they create.
- Users who in the past asked for the permission to commit code into the Drupal.org CVS repository. Now Drupal.org uses Git (in particular an instance of Gitlab running on a drupal.org sub-domain), but the users who asked to be able to write in the Drupal.org CVS repository had the *vetted* role given them.

**Disclaimer**

I am one of the users who has reviewed the requests to get the *vetted* role since the time Drupal.org used CVS.

Comment: Interesting, and great answer Kiamlaluno ;-)